# Very slow Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

Using Java, i want to detect if a line starts with words and separator then "myword", but this regex takes too long. What is incorrect ?

```
^\s*(\w+(\s|/|&|-)*)*myword
```

Comment: What do you mean by *takes too long*? The pattern is too long? Or it takes long to return the result with some specific input?

Comment: With this example "DEPUIS JUILLET 2011 Consultant Montreal" it's not returning any result below 60 seconds

Comment: You need `String rx = "^\\s*(\\w+(?:[\\s/&-]+\\w+)*)[\\s/&-]+myword";`, check http://ideone.com/CT4ENA

Comment: Thanks it's working, but why is this one more efficient ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `^\s*(\w+(\s|/|&|-)*)*myword` is not efficient due to the nested quantifier. `\w+` requires at least one word character and `(\s|/|&|-)*` can match zero or more of some characters. When the `*` is applied to the group and the input string has no separators in between word characters, the expression becomes similar to a `(\w+)*` pattern that is a classical [catastrophical backtracking issue](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) pattern.

Just a small illustration of `\w+` and `(\w+)*` performance:

`\w+`:	                                                `(\w+)*`

[image] [image]

You pattern is even more complicated and invloves more those backtracking steps. To avoid such issues, a pattern should not have optional subpatterns inside quantified groups. That is, create a group with *obligatory subpatterns* and apply the necessary quantifier to the group.

In this case, you can unroll the group you have as

```
String rx = "^\\s*(\\w+(?:[\\s/&-]+\\w+)*)[\\s/&-]+myword";
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/CT4ENA)

Here, `(\w+(\s|/|&|-)*)*` is unrolled as `(\w+(?:[\s/&-]+\w+)*)` (I kept the outer parentheses to produce a capture group #1, you may remove these brackets if you are not interested in them). `\w+` matches one or more word characters (so, it is an obligatory subpatter), and the `(?:[\s/&-]+\w+)*` subpattern matches zero or more (`*`, thus, this whole group is optional) sequences of one or more characters from the defined character class `[\s/&-]+` (so, it is obligatory) followed with one or more word characters `\w+`.